# What does this genome file from NCBI means?

Tags: genome

I obtained a genome from NCBI. For instance, Haloquadratum walsbyi strain AM180088.1. But the FASTA file contain two parts. The first part marked as

**>AM180088.1 Haloquadratum walsbyi DSM 16790 complete genome**

The second part marked as

**>AM180089.1 Haloquadratum walsbyi DSM 16790 plasmid PL47 complete genome**

What does that mean? In particular, the second one "plasmid"? If it is called complete genome should it all in one? Why divide into parts?

Comment: Archea can have plasmids last time I checked...

Comment: what does that mean? So, plasmid have different gene from other part of archaea?

Comment: Yes, bacteria and sometimes both archea and eukaryotes can have plasmids (google the term if you don't know it) in addition to their normal genome.

Comment: I know they have plasmid. But will the plasmid have different gene from the bacteria/archaea itself?

Comment: Typically, yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and not worth migrating to the biology stackexchange.